# How to read wildcards in python?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, byte, cheat-engine

In Cheat Engine we can use "??" as wildcards and those are placeholders for any byte.

What is a wildcard in python?

```
import pymem

def search_pattern_in_dll(process_name, dll_name, pattern):
    process = pymem.Pymem(process_name)

    # Find the base address of the specified DLL
    dll_base_address = 0
    for module in process.list_modules():
        if module.name.lower() == dll_name.lower():
            dll_base_address = module.lpBaseOfDll
            break

    if not dll_base_address:
        print(f"Error: DLL '{dll_name}' not found in the process.")
        return

    # Read the entire DLL's memory
    dll_memory = process.read_bytes(dll_base_address, module.SizeOfImage)

    # Search for the pattern in the DLL's memory
    position = dll_memory.find(bytes(pattern))

    if position != -1:
        address = dll_base_address + position
        print(f"Pattern found at address: 0x{address:X}")
    else:
        print("Pattern not found.")

# Example usage
process_name = "app.exe"
dll_name = "module.dll"
pattern = [0x00, None, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
           0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x8F, 0xE4, 0xF7, 0xFB, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x00,
           0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xD0, 0x60, 0x96, 0xB6, 0x3F, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00,
           0x40, 0xFC, 0x6B, 0xB1, 0x3F, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x63, 0x6A, 0xB6, 0x3F, 0x04, 0x00]

search_pattern_in_dll(process_name, dll_name, pattern)
```

I tried giving `None` but this doesn't work.

Comment: [`bytes.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.find) does not recognize any kind of wildcard value and there is no general purpose wildcard concept used throughout Python. You'll have to implement the search yourself.